# Is it possible to use spring hateoas with router function?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-hateoas

Is there a way to use spring hateoas with router function ?

Right now it seems to me that the only way would be to replace my RouterFunction by RestController.

Comment: Can you add more details? Why would it not be possible to use Spring HATEOAS?

Comment: I would like to seamlessly add links to resource. I am trying to make it work with router function at the moment.

Comment: All the example I see seems to be with @restcontroller not with router function. Just adding hateoas to my dependencies makes my endpoint unauthorized

Comment: Seems to work when I don't use the spring boot starter but   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>